# How to implement shared markup between components in Vue.js

Tags: inheritance, vue.js, components

Imagine I have 3 types of users in my app.

each of the 3 types have shared markup html and also their own html.

I want to create a `baseUserComponent` and in 3 components just use the `baseUserComponent` and also their own html.

something like this :

in user type 1:

```
<baseUserComponent>
 html just for type 1
</baseUserComponent>
```

in user type 2:

```
<baseUserComponent>
 html just for type 2
</baseUserComponent>
```

in user type 3:

```
<baseUserComponent>
 html just for type 3
</baseUserComponent>
```

and all of these have some html shared in `baseUserComponent`.

how can I do this in Vue.js ??

thank you :)))

Comment: Did you try [scoped slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots)? You could also simply create three different components and show only one based on the type via `v-if`.

Comment: @BennettDams   thanks but I don't want to put condition because it could be a huge.I want all these 3 components have share html from user and top of that, have their own.. I don't think slot scope is an answer. can you provide an example of that ?